# Check SAP Netweaver and ABAP Version Information

Tags: abap, netweaver, sap-erp

I have the following SAP configuration:

System-->Status
[image]

[image]

SM51:
[image]

Q1. Which release is this:
SAP ERP Central Component (ECC) 5.0: 2004
SAP ERP Central Component (ECC) 6.0: October 2005
SAP enhancement package 1 for SAP ERP 6.0: December 2006
SAP enhancement package 2 for SAP ERP 6.0: July 2007
or later?

Q2. Which SAP Netweaver version i am running on?

Q3. What version of ABAP am i using?

Comment: This might be off-topic. Anyway, please click the magnifying glass in your first screenshot and provide that list as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So-so, you have:

1. **Platform version** is Netweaver 7 (2004s)
2. **SAP ERP release** is 6.0 and it was issued in 2005. 
   Yes, ECC 6.0 was issued particularly in 2005 and your installation date *Aug 29 2006* gives nothing than the installation date.
   You have no Enhancement Packs, only 6th Support Pack.
3. **ABAP version** is 7.0 without any EHP.

More on this can be found [here](http://www.g3g.com/blog/which-version-of-netweaver-am-i-running).

Answer (score 0):

The System Status screens have a little bit evolved since ABAP 7.0. Here they are for ABAP 7.52 SP 0 (SAP_ABA or SAP_BASIS), S/4HANA 1709 On Premise, SAP kernel 7.53 SP 2, HANA 2.0 --Netweaver "version" is meaningless, it's more a marketing name-- :

- Menu System > Status: 
  [image: System Status 7.52]
- Click button Details of Product Version:

  - First tab "Installed Software Component Versions":
    [image: Installed Software Component Versions]
  - Second tab "Installed Product Versions":
    [image: Installed Product Versions]
- Click button Other kernel information:
  [image: Other kernel information]