# ABAP, SQL, Is it possible to handle N-M relation in single query?

Tags: abap

I have not found a way to write a query in ABAP that will provide me a data from tables with N-M relation.

ZTINTF_EMPASS description:

- emp_no - Employee Number
- pos_no - Employee Job Position Number
- start_date - A date when Employee started working at current position

Problem description:

- each pair {emp_no, pos_no} have unique start_date
- for each emp_no the maximum start_date needs to be found and returned with the corresponding pos_no

Query example possible for SQL Server (with clause contains data just for simulation):

```
with ztintf_empass (mandt, emp_no, pos_no, start_date) as (
select 100, '000000001001', 101, CONVERT(DATETIME, '01.07.2014', 102) union all
select 100, '000000001002', 102, CONVERT(DATETIME, '01.06.2014', 102) union all
select 100, '000000001003', 102, CONVERT(DATETIME, '01.01.2000', 102) union all
select 100, '000000001003', 103, CONVERT(DATETIME, '01.01.2010', 102) union all
select 100, '000000001004', 202, CONVERT(DATETIME, '01.01.2000', 102) union all
select 100, '000000001005', 201, CONVERT(DATETIME, '01.06.2016', 102) union all
select 100, '000000001005', 301, CONVERT(DATETIME, '01.05.2015', 102) union all
select 100, '000000001006', 401, CONVERT(DATETIME, '01.01.2000', 102) union all
select 100, '000000001006', 402, CONVERT(DATETIME, '01.09.2010', 102) union all
select 100, '000000001006', 403, CONVERT(DATETIME, '01.10.2015', 102) union all
select 100, '000000001006', 501, CONVERT(DATETIME, '01.03.2019', 102) 
) 
select a.emp_no
     , pos_no
     , a.start_date 
  from ztintf_empass a
       inner join (
           select emp_no
                , max(start_date) start_date
             from ztintf_empass 
            group by emp_no
       ) g on g.emp_no = a.emp_no
          and g.start_date = a.start_date
;
```

I do want to make exact result with single query in ABAP.

Expected result:

```
emp_no        pos_no  start_date
000000001001  101     01.07.2014
000000001002  102     01.06.2014
000000001003  103     01.01.2010
000000001004  202     01.01.2000
000000001005  201     01.06.2016
000000001006  501     01.03.2019
```

I have spent some time on that with no effect - is it possible?

Comment: Are you looking for a cartesian product? If so, I think the [CROSS JOIN](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/10/26/abap-news-release-7.51-cross-join-open-sql-abap-cds/) is the way to go.

Comment: I have added the result that I guess you expect. Please confirm that it's correct. Moreover, please tell us your ABAP version.

Comment: Dear Sandra, you do not need to guess as the content which you have added is the result of the query execution (if only online tool is an option here is a handy service: https://rextester.com/l/sql_server_online_compiler), and the query is correct. ABAP version is not old with 760 GUI client. If that information should be more precise I can ask internally,

Comment: The [ABAP version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40243603/check-sap-netweaver-and-abap-version-information) is important to know because ABAP SQL evolved a lot in the last versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You suppose very strange limitation of some relationship between data, but ABAP does not know anything of your data, so it let you to make joins between tables with any (possibly no) relation. The syntax of `SELECT` is available in [ABAP help](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abapfrom_clause.htm). Here you can find that there's no place for subquery in `data_source` definition.

The workarounds of this are:

- [CDS view](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abenddic_cds_views.htm) with more SQL options available. Also you can create an aggregating view and use it as data source.
- For HANA there's [AMDP methods for classes](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abenamdp.htm), where you can write any valid SQLScript code for HANA database. Here you declare DDIC objects in method definition,  so where-used list will show you usage of objects in repository. Also you can call non-ABAP objects, available in DBMS, with schema-prefixed identifier: `schema.object`.
- [`CL_SQL_STATEMENT`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abencl_sql_statement.htm) class, where you can write any valid SQL statement for your database. But there's, of course, no SQL syntax check or any where-used functionality.

Comment: Dear astentx, thank you for answer. I have spent some time with ABAP manual and indeed I have not found the interesting solution there. I am learning, and I did not believed that what I wanted achieve is not an option with ABAP implementation of SQL.
I am not able to work with CDS yet, so I will check the other to options.

Comment: @J3W You're welcome! Limitations that you can face while trying to put not so complicated SQL into ABAP Open SQL are mostly caused by "universal solution" for all the DBMS supported, because Open SQL is part of ABAP syntax. I do not know why some very simple operations like `IN` predicate with multiple fields are not supported in OpenSQL (because every enterprise DBMS can handle that), but this is the fact: OpenSQL is very limited and most of times still forces you to move data back and forth from DB to app server or use SQL classes to execute queries. Hope you'll have a good time with ABAP